# Error using "xp_sprintf": Invalid Parameter Type

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to write/run some SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @result varchar(max);
EXEC xp_sprintf @result OUTPUT, 'Name: %s', 'John';
```

However, when I run it, I get this error message:

> Error executing extended stored procedure: Invalid Parameter Type
>
> Msg 50003, Level 1, State 0

Everything looks OK to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that it didn't like me using `varchar(max)` as the result variable type. Changing it to use a length other than `max` fixed the problem:

```
DECLARE @result varchar(255);
EXEC xp_sprintf @result OUTPUT, 'Name: %s', 'John';
```

Comment: FORMATMESSAGE seems to be a better option is you need more than 255: http://pmichaels.net/2016/07/06/sql-server-xp_sprintf-and-xp_sscanf/